# How to pass arguments to soapui test case from another test case which using Run Test Case step

Tags: soapui

Using soapui open source edition. I know this question is very basic, but somehow missing something and not able to pass argument value to `template test case`.

There are multiple test steps in a test case. And there are multiple tests with different data. So, this can be done in different ways. And I am trying the 2nd approach. Also looked at the soapui's [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/teststep-reference/run-testcase.html), nothing has mentioned something like this.

1. Create test case with all the steps required. Clone test case for number of times and change the data. Which is not smart way.
2. Create one test case, name it as `basicTestCaseTemplate`. Assume it has 3 soap request steps and each request is using a property and use property expansion instead of static test values such as `${#TestCase#ID}`. Then use the above template case in different test cases using a test step called `Run Test Case`, passing value of ID from here. However, value ID  is not being passed to requests of `templateTestCase`. Basically wanted to reuse the test steps.
   Any ideas?

Please note that I can use groovy step instead of `Run Test Case` as alternative like the documentation says. But I think, this is something very basic and should work or doing some trival mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is something related with your *SOAPUI* version, I try to reproduce your problem using *SOAPUI 5.0.0*, so I create a *TestSuite* which contains two *TestCases*.

In the first *TestCase* I simply add a *Test Step SOAP Request* which in his request it use as you comment the follow property using property expansion `${#TestCase#ID}`. Also I add on the *Custom Properties* tab of this *Test Case* the `ID` property with `original ID` as value :

[image]

In the second *TestCase* I create a *Run TestCase* step, and there I specify the template *TestCase* as a *TestCase* to run. Automatically this *TestStep* recognize the *TestCase ID property* and allows me to assign a different value for it in this context:

[image]

Now If I run the *Run TestCase* in the *http log* tab I can see the request with the modified `ID`:

```
Wed May 04 13:24:15 CEST 2016:DEBUG:>> "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:profiles:archive">[\n]"
Wed May 04 13:24:15 CEST 2016:DEBUG:>> "   <soapenv:Body>[\n]"
Wed May 04 13:24:15 CEST 2016:DEBUG:>> "   [0x9]different ID from Run TestCase step[\n]"
Wed May 04 13:24:15 CEST 2016:DEBUG:>> "   </soapenv:Body>[\n]"
Wed May 04 13:24:15 CEST 2016:DEBUG:>> "</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

Note: Seems that if you don't explicitly add the property on *Custom property* tab of the template *TestCase*, the *Run TestCase step* don't give you the option to set the property value (even if you're using the property expansion on the request). I think that your problem could be on this.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you @albciff. Learnt that I overlooked at the parameters of Run Test Case step which you showed in your screen shot. Worked in 4.5.1 as well. However, also wanted to use the return property value from Template, some how not sure of it.

Comment: just happened to do a [sample project](https://github.com/nmrao/sample-soapui-projects/tree/master/run-test-case) with return value. And I welcome if you got any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

1. In my case the value set when running the test case was always deleted when I executed the test step.
2. Then I noticed that it was actually overwriting it with the original value defined in the original test case.
3. Then I realised that the checkbox "Return Properties" was set for the parameter.
4. After I unchecked that checkbox it worked like intended.

So always just tick that checkbox for parameters that contain a result, because the value you pass won't make it into the test case otherwise.